# JSX - dynamically rendering local images

Tags: reactjs, image

I'm trying to map through an array of objects, rendering local images, but have painfully found out that this can't be done the same way as rendering external urls, with the images not firing.

Not been able to find a solution without cheating and declaring local images declaratively - import Logo from ... - or placing the images in the public folder, which could give me cache issues down the line. I've tried image: require("") in the array but it doesn't seem to respond.

Surely this can be done dynamically? If anyone knows of a solution to the below it would really help me out.

Directory.jsx

```
    this.state = {
        categories: [
            {
                title: "Burgers",
                image: "../../images/Burger_landing.jpeg",
                id: 1
            },
            {
                title: "Sides",
                image: "../../images/Fries_main.jpeg",
                id: 2
            },
            {
                title: "Shakes",
                image: "../../images/Shakes_main.jpeg",
                id: 3
            }
        ]
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className='menu__container-position'>
            {this.state.categories.map(({ title, image, id }) => (
                <DirectoryItem key={id} title={title} image={image} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

DirectoryItem.jsx

```
const DirectoryItem = ({ title, image }) => {
return (
    <div
        className='menu__container-img'
        style={{ backgroundImage: `${image}` }}
    >
        <h1>{title}</h1>
    </div>
);
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the image URL like below

```
backgroundImage: `url(${image})`
```

Or

```
backgroundImage: "url("+image+")"
```

If images are not in a public path

```
 backgroundImage: `url(${require(image)})`
```

Comment: Brilliant, that's the syntax I was looking for but just couldn't find. Thanks!